# A question on resolutions of coherent sheaves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

If $A$ is a commutative unital ring and $E$ is a finite rank projective $A$-module there is a surjective $A$-linear map $\phi: A^n \rightarrow E$, with kernel $F:=ker(\phi)$ and $F\oplus E \cong A^n$ an isomorphism of $A$-modules. We get a short exact sequence of projective finite rank $A$-modules

$$ 0 \rightarrow F \rightarrow A^n \rightarrow E \rightarrow 0 .$$

There is a canonical projection map (an $A$-linear map)

$$ \psi: A^n \rightarrow F$$

with $ker(\psi)=E$. Using a "splicing-technique" we get an infinite exact sequence of free $A$-modules

$$ \cdots \rightarrow A^n \rightarrow A^n \rightarrow A^n \rightarrow E \rightarrow 0.$$

Hence $E$ has an infinite free resolution by projective (and free) $A$-modules of finite rank.

If $k$ is a field and $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n_k$ is a regular projective scheme there is for any coherent sheaf $F$ an infinite resolution by finite direct sums of invertible sheaves:

Hartshorne Corr. II.5.18 says: If $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n_k$ is projective, it follows any coherent sheaf $F$ is a quotient

$$ f_1:\oplus_{i(1)=1}^{N(1)} \mathcal{O}(n(1)_{i(1)}) \rightarrow F \rightarrow 0.$$

It follows $X:=Proj(k[x_1,..,x_n]/I)$ with $B:=k[x_i]/I$ noetherian. Hence if $F$ is a coherent module it follow any submodule $E \subseteq F$ is coherent. It follows $\oplus \mathcal{O}(n(1)_i)$ is coherent hence $ker(f_1)$ is a coherent module. Hence there is a surjection

$$ f_2: \oplus_{i(2)}^{N(2)} \mathcal{O}(n(2)_{i(2)} \rightarrow ker(f_1)$$

and continuing this process you get a long exact sequence of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules

$$S1.\text{   }\cdots \rightarrow  \oplus_{i(2)}^{N(2)} \mathcal{O}(n(2)_{i(2)}) \rightarrow  \oplus_{i(1)=1}^{N(1)} \mathcal{O}(n(1)_{i(1)}) \rightarrow F \rightarrow 0.$$

**Example:** If $X$ is projective space and $F$ a finite rank locally free sheaf it follows the sequence S1 terminates - it is finite. A similar property holds for the grassmannian. As a consequence it follows the Grothendieck group of projective space (and the grassmannian) is generated by classes of invertible sheaves.

**General question:** Can you give an explicit example of a projective regular scheme $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n_k$ and a finite rank locally trivial (and non-trivial) $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $F$ with a resolution S1 that is infinite? Please give an explicit reference to the litterature.

**Special case:** If $A \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n_K$ is an abelian variety with $K$ a number field - give an explicit example of a finite rank non-trivial vector bundle $F$ on $A$ with a resolution as in S1 that is infinite.

By "non-trivial" I mean: $F$ is not a direct sum of invertible sheaves.

**Note:** If $k:=\overline{K}$ is the algebraic closure of $K$ and if $A\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n_k$ is an abelian variety, any homogeneous finite rank vector bundle $E$ is on the form

$$ E\cong \oplus_{L\in Pic^0(A)} L\otimes U_L$$

where $U_L$ is an iterated extension of trivial bundles. Hence in the grothendieck group $K_0(A)$ we get

$$ [L\otimes U_L]=[L]*[U_L]$$

and $[U_L]=rk(U_L)[\mathcal{O}_A]$ hence

$$[L\otimes U_L]=[L]rk(U_L)[\mathcal{O}_A]=rk(U_L)[L]$$

and

$$[E]= \oplus_{L\in Pic^0(A)} rk(U_L)[L].$$

Hence for a homogeneous finite rank vector-bundle $E$ it follows the sequence S1 is finite. Hence in this case it follows the class $[E]\in K_0(A)$ lives in the sub group generated by classes of invertible sheaves. I'm looking for explicit examples where this does not hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a smooth 4-dimensional quadric $Q \subset \mathbb{P}^5$ and a plane $\Pi \subset Q$. Then the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_\Pi$ of the plane can't have a finite resolution by direct sums of line bundles because the cohomology class $$[\Pi] \in H^4(Q,\mathbb{Z})$$ does not lie in the subring of $H^\bullet(Q,\mathbb{Q})$ generated by divisors.